# TypeScript seems to be seeing a variable as 'any' even though it's defined

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, sass, css-modules

I have the following component:

```
import React from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames';

import styles from './styles.module.scss';

const cx = classNames.bind(styles);

interface Props {
  /**
   * Allows a user to apply a custom class
   */
  className?: string;
  /**
   * The content to show in the button
   */
  children: ReactNode;
  /**
   * The if you want to include an icon, this specifies the side of the button the icon should appear on
   */
  alignIcon?: 'left' | 'right';
  /**
   * The event action to fire when the button is clicked
   */
  onClick?: (fn) => void;
}


/* Render component */
export const Button = React.forwardRef<HTMLButtonElement, Props>(
  ({ alignIcon, className, onClick, children }: Props, ref) => (
    <button
      ref={ref}
      className={cx(
        styles['button'],
        alignIcon && styles[`icon-${alignIcon}`],
        className
      )}
      onClick={onClick}
    >
      {children}
    </button>
  )
);

Button.displayName = 'Button';

export default Button;
```

It works exactly as I would want it to, however I get the following error when I run `tsc`

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'CssExports'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type
```

It appears to not like the use of the variable as if I replace `` styles[`icon-${alignIcon}`] `` with `styles['icon-left']` or `styles['icon-right']`, the error goes away. I'm unsure where the implied any is coming from.

In addition, here is the generated `styles.modules.scss.d.ts` file which has the `CssExports` in it:

```
interface CssExports {
  'button': string;
  'error': string;
  'icon': string;
  'icon-left': string;
  'icon-none': string;
  'icon-right': string;
}
export const cssExports: CssExports;
export default cssExports;
```

Comment: Have you tried making `alignIcon` non-optional (e.g. `alignIcon: 'left' | 'right';`) ? Maybe because its optional tsc assumes that `icon-${alignIcon}` might become `icon- `, which is not in CssExports

Comment: Yeah. I've tried that unfortunatley.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the issue in other components too, so I 'resolved' the issue by just adding a generic `scss-modules.d.ts` file to the project and removing all of the specific ones. If anyone is interested, that file looks like this:

```
declare module "*.scss" {
  const styles: { [className: string]: string };     
  export default styles; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to cast the variable explicitly: `` styles[`icon-${alignIcon}`] as CssExports ``.

Alternatively, you can suppress this error by adding the following to your `tsconfig.json` compilerOptions:

```
compilerOptions: {
  "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
}
```

Comment: Sadly the first option didn't work and the second suggestion isn't really an option IMO.

Comment: I had the issue in other components too, so I 'resolved' the issue by just adding a generic `scss-modules.d.ts` file to the project and removing all of the specific ones. If anyone is interested, that file looks like this:

```declare module "*.scss" {
    const styles: { [className: string]: string };
    export default styles;
}```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your `alignIcon` param is optional, so it might be null. Make sure that you handle this case by having some default value there:

```js
export const Button = ({ alignIcon = "left", className, onClick, children }: Props, ref) => {
    /* element body */
})
```